# Is it possible to listen to all notification in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone development. I would like to know whether is there any technique to listen to all the incoming notifications in a windows phone ?
For example, if I had an application( developed in C# ) and if I receive an email notification( a new email ), a call, an sms, a reminder or any third party notifications( like a new message in whatsapp ), I need to get these notifications in my C# application. Is this possible  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, is not possible.
You can listen to notifications of your own app only.